# Parsing command line parameters string

Tags: c#, .net, string

This will seem a strange question so I will explain it as simply as possible. I am making an app like CMD in C# and I need to have commands like 'ping'. I have a switch statement that checks the command entered and executes it. This is:

```
switch (CommandName)
{
    case "intro":
        {
            Console.WriteLine("intro");
            CommandListen();
        }
        break;

    case "clear":
        {
            CommandFolder.CmdClear cmd = new CommandFolder.CmdClear();
            cmd.Execute();
            CommandListen();
        }
        break;

    case "ping":
        {
            CommandFolder.CmdPing cmd = new CommandFolder.CmdPing();
            cmd.Execute(CommandName);
            CommandListen();
        }
        break;

    case "exit":
        {
            CommandFolder.CmdExit cmd = new CommandFolder.CmdExit();
            cmd.Execute();
        }
        break;

    default:
        CommandListen();
        break;
}
```

I have no idea how to get it to work with parameters for a command, i.e. ping [ip/url] [extra]. If I enter 'ping' it works and executes the command, but if I enter 'ping www.google.com' it comes up with my unrecognized command error. I need a way to check the first part of the command, and then pass the parameters through.

I apologize if this is vague, I just didn't know how to word it.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to split the string on space?

Comment: Try this library - https://commandline.codeplex.com/

Comment: Your code is looking at `CommandName`, which has presumably been set from user input somewhere. In the code where you capture that value, you need to split the user's input into the "command" and the "parameters" rather than just passing through the whole thing. Have you got anything like this in place? If not, you need to be looking at "parsing" tutorials that will show you how to break a string down into recognised chunks.

Comment: @DanPuzey yes it has been set and i don't have anything in place like that, but i will definitely have a look. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a syntax and write a parser for that. As @Lasse and @Dan suggested in the comments, it can be as simple as "a command and its parameters are separated by one space", which will make a naive implementation of the parsing code look like this:

```
string commandParts = CommandName.Split(" ");
string commandName = commandParts[0];
var arguments = commandParts.Skip(1).ToList();

var command = new SomeCommand(arguments);
```

This code splits the input on space (" "), takes the first result as the command and the optional remainder as arguments (no arguments entered will become an empty `arguments` list).

You'll of course need to add code for error handling for when no command is entered, or adjust the split code if you want to support multiple spaces being entered.